# Load Firestore data to Table view Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question related to load data from Firestore to table view. Basically, i understand how to do it, but in this case, i kind of confuse if the structure of Firestore as below:

"fund" -> "randomId" -> "agensi: id"

[image: fund]

i was able to load the agensi from collection which is "WJ18kBvDLhVrvml2slXB". To get the real agensi name i have to get data from collection "Agensi" as image below:

[image]

below is the code that what i have already did:

```
var agencyname: [String] = []

    func getData()  {

    db.collection("fund").getDocuments()
        {
            (querySnapshot, err) in

            if let err = err
            {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
            }
            else
            {
                //  var agencyNumber = 0
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let agency = data["agensi"] as? String ?? ""
                    let agencyId = document.documentID
                    print(agency)
                    print(agencyId)
                    //MARK get name

                    let newdocRef = Firestore.firestore().document("Agensi/\(agency)")

                    newdocRef.getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
                        guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else { return }
                        let dataDetails = docSnapshot.data()

                        let agencyNew = dataDetails!["name"] as? String ?? ""

                        self.agencyname.append(agencyNew)
                        print("List of the agency: \(self.agencyname.append(agencyNew))")

                    }

                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
    }
}
```

i try to print:

> self.agencyname.append(agencyNew)

but its display nothing. so, i cannot load the name of the agency into my table view cell. By the way sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you please mind to accept the answer or any feedback if there is any issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things I would like to tell:

**1.** `FireStore` queries are asynchronous so there is a callback function when it finishes. Reload your `tableView` inside the callback instead of end of the loop only then it will load the data properly.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()   
}
```

Write above code just below `print("List of the agency: \(self.agencyname.append(agencyNew))")` line.

**2.** You're printing `"self.agencyname.append(agencyNew)"` and it is `void` by the way so will not print anything so `print(\(self.agencyname))` instead.

**3.** When using a `guard` in a `loop` then don't use `return` because it will break the loop for next iteration if any error occurs. We should use `continue` here to let the loop execute completely.